# Make it easy for me to link to a book on Amazon.com (and earn money for Stack Exchange at the same time)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, amazon

Often the answer to a question contains a reference to a book. **This might as well point at Amazon.com in such a way as Stack Exchange earns the commission**.

Comment: Kyle, I guess the main point was the one in parentheses, i.e. potentially earning money for SO, which your method doesn't do, I think.

Comment: @Kyle: That link doesn't have an Amazon Affiliate "tag" attribute, and so doesn't earn any money for SO.

Comment: @Jonik, @Bill: Yes, my link is a regular link, but I was addressing the "Make it easy for me to link to a book on Amazon" part, not the "earn money for Stackoverflow" part. Basically I was demonstrating that it's easy enough already to link to a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has now been done

Answer (score 4):

And what if someone wants to have their own affiliate tag in the link so that THEY can potentially make a little money?

I am not a fan of either, and I have seen numerous times where people who add affiliate information get flagged as spam. I don't like the idea of StackOverflow covertly changing my links to insert their own affiliate information. That is pretty shady.

Comment: I've suggested before (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10948/would-it-be-a-problem-if-all-amazon-links-were-converted-to-affiliate-links/10958#10958): How about if they refrained from transforming links that already contained an affiliate link a certain percentage of the time. I'd see it as something of a reward for contributing to the upkeep of the site. By explicitly allowing the posting of affiliate links it would encourage users to post more Amazon links which would (hopefully) increase the revenue Jeff and Co could generate from such a scheme.

Comment: discussed here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=amazon+affiliate