# How can we prevent a large number of approved suggested edits by one user from cluttering up the home page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, homepage

On Programmers, I just came across a user who was [using suggested edits to add Amazon links](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2580/2314) to many questions. This user was [advised to limit the edits to avoid cluttering up the homepage with many edits](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2582/2314).

At a practical sense given the current functionality of the home page, I can understand the reasoning.  But it seems silly to advise users not to do something helpful on those grounds.

Can we do better?

Comment: Related: [Do we care about edit flooding? Should we be doing anything?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3103/)

Comment: and [Are edits to include Amazon links to books appropriate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111054)

Comment: See also: [How to prevent users applying a policy without agreement?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/how-to-prevent-users-applying-a-policy-without-agreement)

Comment: As well as: [Approve suggested edits when only the signature is removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/approve-suggested-edits-when-only-the-signature-is-removed)

Comment: What do you mean with "Can we do better?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the help with the title -- however -- I'm not suggesting that prevention is the only solution.  I'm wondering whether we should change our advice *or* prevent clutter of the homepage.  But, as you commented on the meta.programmers post, I think it's silly to weight the appropriateness of an edit based on how many of them are done. (@kiamlaluno, this should answer your question too)

Comment: Rather than complicating this with yet another Meta post, I'm just going to [feature-request] this one.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bumping posts to the front page when a substantial edit occurs is [by-design].  It allows the community to review the edits to see if they are appropriate.

Perhaps a throttle could be added to suggested edits by an individual user.  I suggest a restriction of *six suggested edits per hour per user.*  I think that would solve the problem at hand, and still give editors plenty of leeway to suggest *substantial* edits.

Comment: While the number might still be pretty high for low-traffic sites, I definitely think this is a reasonable compromise between trying to keep the front page fresh and allowing low-rep users to help out.

Comment: Just a thought: Should not the limit consider when the post has been created? For example, if I am editing a post created 2 minutes ago, I am not cluttering the front page; vice versa, if I am editing a question asked a month ago, which has already an accepted answer, I am surely doing more "damage."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The only people that are likely to hit this limit are editors who are adding Amazon links or deleting the word "hell" from posts, among other similar reasons. It is unlikely that a person doing more substantive editing will hit this limit.

Comment: I understood the reason for restricting the edits; still, it's not cluttering the front page, if I edit a question that has been asked 2 minutes ago. I am not sure the limit would be hit only by who removes the word "hell" from titles; there is also who removes sentences similar to "As this question has been closed here, I asked the same question on […]."

Comment: The clutter is a symptom of the problem, not the problem itself. The actual problem is finding an acceptable way to edit posts, and then performing that same edit on many, many posts. The rate limit solves both the symptom and the actual underlying problem. It should be a simple rate limiter; I don't want to make the logic too complicated for people to understand, or too onerous for the developers to implement.

Comment: I believe that any edit will cause a bump, not just a substantial edit. I feel that minor edits - adding/removing a link, changing tags, and edits of less than a specific percentage of a post should not cause a bump. It would remedy a lot of problems. Then, the limit could just be applied to substantial edits that cause a post to be bumped.