# Amazon links in comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, amazon, affiliate

Sorry if this is a dup, but I couldn't find it.

It seems that the [Amazon affiliate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) code doesn't work for [links placed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956491/aima-in-disgrace).

Answer (score 3):

Replicated [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/what-are-some-good-systems-for-a-space-opera-style-game/2069#2069).  I'm not sure how many amazon links are in comments, but clicks are money.

Comment: you seem to have the wronge link

Comment: @IanRingrose No the comment on that post shows the issue as well.

Comment: @C. Ross, but it is not a duplicate of this question

Comment: @Ian Ringrose I meant replicated.  I edited to say so.

Comment: 2000, as of right now... meh.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Also replicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883998/328193).  It looks like this is a pretty old question, but it's better to bump it than to ask a new one.