# Should the Amazon affiliate URLs be improved by including titles?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, amazon, affiliate

Some time ago when answering a question about learning resources, I posted a couple of Amazon links. To my dismay, I noticed that the links were converted to rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/...

Then I came here to find an explanation and stumbled upon [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

I am sure the auto-insertion of links is necessary and useful but it also creates confusion: people usually look at the status bar before clicking a link. When it's an Amazon link, they instantly see the product title without having to go on that specific page.

However **currently the affiliate link feature deletes that information**, resulting in useless noise posts such as "Yeah yeah, but I know a better book. Oh..wait.. I didn't click the link to see that the book you suggested is actually the same one I am talking about".

I propose that the Amazon affiliate links preserved the product title visible in the original URL.

Comment: FWIW, some corporate networks don't allow Amazon.  It was classified as a shopping site on ours, and I had to ask special to be allowed to get to it.  Ideally, of course, the author and title would be listed along with the URL.

Comment: @David, I think you need to visit http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ at least they added it when you asked.

Comment: @Ian:  This is, overall, a very good job.  I usually don't notice the filtering (except when it blocks ads, which I'm not going to complain about), and when I needed an exception I got it within the day.