# Auto Inserting Amazon affiliate links take me to the wrong Amazon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, amazon

I live in the Republic of Ireland which is served by amazon.co.uk. The rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/ redirector sends me to amazon.com.

According to this article, the redirector should use IP geolocation to send you to the most appropriate Amazon site:

> [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)
>
> We have a clever affiliate redirect
>   that geolocates the IP and redirects
>   to the appropriate regional Amazon
>   store (amazon.uk, amazon.ca, et
>   cetera).

Can the Amazon link redirector be changed to redirect to amazon.co.uk for Irish IP addresses?

Comment: Pretty sure we've discussed this before... pretty sure it was declined. It would be nice, though.

Comment: @Jon Siegel: This question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links shows effort to redirect IPs to a relevant Amazon store based on country. I don't see any evidence of this being declined.

Comment: @greg - thanks I was looking for that.

Comment: Okay, I take it all back. My bad! @Greg

Comment: Odd that Amazon doesn't take care of this.

Comment: @will - how/why would it? If I browse (normally) to the .com site it knows I'm in Ireland and suggests I might want to shop on the .co.uk but it doesn't redirect me. It does does this on UK connections too. It's your geolocator that's not picking the the correct amazon.

Comment: @Kev I'd think Amazon would want to redirect users to the site that's geographically closer to them.  But I'm not a web dev who works on international sites, so I honestly don't know enough to comment anymore on the subject.  BTW, I'm a janitor here, not an architect.

Comment: @will - they don't and never have. The stores differ in the products they carry and they don't muck about with shipping restrictions unless a vendor such as Apple (typically) prevent sales of goods outside the US. So back to your mop and bucket duties :D

Comment: I have the same problem. I am from Germany and the link is not redirecting me to amazon.de (which would be great for wishlists etc..)

Comment: I have the same problem - I'm in the UK and 91.223.10.1 isn't being geolocated properly.

Comment: @will - any chance of poking the dev team to have a look at this?

Comment: @Kev: team@stackoverflow.com is your best bet.  I'm just a janitor; the architects just throw wadded up blueprints at me and snicker behind my back.

Comment: @will - lol - ok :)

Comment: @Richard, @örs, @will - see my answer which explains all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got a reply from Jeff explaining why the GeoLocator doesn't work any more:

> It's a long story, but unless we
> operate a business in the UK,
> officially, we can't get affiliate
> income from Amazon there anyway .. so
> we don't geolocate amazon stuff any
> more, and have not for a while.
>
> some details here
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/
>
> but that bit is quite important and
> not covered there.

Which is fair enough.

Comment: Annoying - the geolocator is really handy because as a UK'er, it was really handy to click a link and get UK amazon.  Also, why not just select a suitable cause and donate your affiliate links to them?

Comment: @richard - yeah, but it is as it is. TBH I get most of my books from computermanuals.co.uk in the UK. Better prices, better service and they usually deliver by courier.