# How can we link to products that exist on amazon.co.uk but not amazon.com without the auto-inserted affiliate link breaking?

Tags: bug, status-completed, amazon, affiliate

I understand that the amazon.com links are [automatically updated to include the affiliate link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)
However, some products appear only in the .co.uk Amazon domain.  For example, the following link (which I have intentionally broken) does not work when converted to our affiliate link:

amazon.co.uk/dp/B0015NLFFA

Is there a way to get .co.uk-only products linked properly?

Comment: We have the [same problem](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/256/162) on the Japanese site.  Some of the reference material (dictionaries, grammar guides, etc) are not available on the US version of Amazon.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75594/auto-inserting-amazon-affiliate-links-take-me-to-the-wrong-amazon/92042#92042

Comment: @Kev its not so much an issue of "it would be nice if it pointed us to the localized Amazon domain", but rather "not all Amazon domains share the same product base, so if something specific to Amazon.uk.co is linked, the link *breaks*".

Comment: Yes that does seem messy, hadn't bumped into that before.

Comment: [Another example](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/gaming-promotional-grant-fall-2011-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/2876#2876).

Comment: Here's [another example](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3357/162) (this one hasn't been deleted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon links that are not to the US .com site will no longer be redirected to it.

Amazon requires that you have a physical business location in a country to use an affiliate link, so we aren't affiliates in other countries.  We will no longer replace these with .com, we just won't touch them.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove affiliate codes, even if you can't substitute your own for non US amazon links.

Comment: well, technically we have a presence in the UK (two employees) but I'm not sure what else is necessary, etc.