# What purpose does rads.stackoverflow.com serve?

Tags: discussion

I saw a link to http://rads.stackoverflow.com in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/252939/139479).

The link took me to a book in Amazon website. http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/

So, I'll just repeat the title: **What purpose does rads.stackoverflow.com serve?**

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87136/hey-youre-not-eeeeking-out-the-maximum-profit-you-could-be-on-amazon-links. You see here it has to do with Amazon referral links.