# What link should I post when making reference to a book?

Tags: discussion, support, books

When we are making a reference to a book in our answer/question...

**What link should I place?**

- Original page book
- Wikipedia
- Amazon

---

I'm just asking because maybe SE could earn some comission in some book stores for each people that buys a book which page was accessed through some SE site. Don't know.

Answer (score 4):

SE actually [add their affiliate ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)  to all Amazon links you post.

Linking to Amazon is pretty much the de-facto social standard. Understandably so - they have the best features, offer the most information plus "look inside" pictures, related books, prices for new and used versions, and so on.

If there is a Wikipedia page, that *might* be preferable though IMO - it is a more neutral source of information, and will contain the ISBN number necessary to find it on Amazon.

Comment: It is good to know about Amazon...