# Link to commercial site: is it spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

Here is a really [poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447714/java-barcode-scanner-with-java) with mainly a link to amazon.

I'm pretty sure the initial intention of the OP was not promotional, but anyway the link remains.

Should this kind of question be flagged as spam?

Comment: I don't think it's spam. It's just a crap, off-topic, question.

Comment: on a side note, all [links to Amazon are rewritten to use the SO Affiliate link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) so the only way the OP could benefit from inserting that link is when he is the vendor of the device.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not spam, it's just a poor question with a link to whatever device the person is trying to figure out how to interface with.

If the OP doesn't improve the question, it will eventually get deleted. Right now, it's fine simply being closed.