# Brand / organization specific tags on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Do brand/organization specific tags such as [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon) or [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft) provide any value on Meta Stack Overflow? I think they should not be allowed otherwise we would be opening gates for all kinds of tags such as *samsung* or *nokia* and others.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the questions I see many instances where they make sense. Don't you think so?

Comment: *My OCD sense is tingling* The tags make it seem like you skipped a line between Meta Stack and Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Meta they make sense. There are questions about the impact of the given company on Stack Overflow, and the questions about something having impact on Stack Overflow belongs to Meta. Because the impact is caused by the phenomenon called Amazon or Microsoft in that particular case, so are the [amazon](/questions/tagged/amazon) and [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft) tags on place.

Comment: Especially Amazon, since [book links to amazon.com get automatically changed to SO affiliate links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)