# Don't auto-replace Amazon links in codeblocks

Tags: bug, code-block, amazon

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325630/displaying-nothing-when-i-am-trying-to-scrape-data-using-simple-html-dom-parser) a user is asking about how to scrape an Amazon URL. The included MCVE contains the URL as a string literal:

> [image: Amazon.com URL in code block highlighted]

However, anyone visiting the question **can't see that URL**, as it is [auto-replaced by the rads.stackoverflow.com affiliate URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) on rendering:

> Here is my code:
>
> ```
> $html1 = file_get_html("http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DDXILBQ");
> $title1 = $html1 - > find("div.sims-fbt-rows,0") - > find("span.p13n-sc-price") - > innertext;
> if ($title1) {
>     echo $title1;
> } else {
>     echo 'problem';
> }
> ```

Please exclude code blocks when auto-redirecting affiliation URLs.

As a temporary work-around, I've split up the string literal into several concatenated pieces.

Comment: Stupid question, but why not just replace it with a `example.com` URL? I doubt the problem lies specifically with the `amazon.com` domain, does it?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: issues with scraping a specific website should definitely name that website. Amazon almost certainly has anti-scraping measures in place.

Comment: Ah, I see - yes that makes sense.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the url rewriting for Amazon was supposed to be disabled as it provided no benefits?

Comment: @JonClements every dime that can be earned, should be earned.

Comment: @rene ahh... my bad... the amazon ads were discontinued, not the link re-writing (ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)