# Intra-word emphasis using Pagedown vs. Stack Exchange's WMD Editor

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

Why does Stack Exchange's WMD Editor allow you to do things like bold pa**rts of sentences** while the Open Source PageDown (https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown) does not?

> [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)

Comment: @Ano Does that post explain why the change is not made in PageDown?

Comment: @FTP That's off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Ano The software that powers Stack Exchange sites is on topic here. PageDown description says "The Markdown editor and converter used on Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites"

Comment: @Ano I dunno, it's an official Stack Exchange library that's very of-interest to some users working on integrated tools. Being able to consistently render posts in the same way as the site [was a specific question I just asked for archival purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307975/134300), and this is vey related.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not available in PageDown? A quick search shows there is an `asteriskIntraWordEmphasis` option that enables `_DoItalicsAndBold_AllowIntrawordWithAsterisk` in [Markdown.Converter.js](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/32c0bdb121de04e0e956ddde0391022644ff1a76/Markdown.Converter.js#L232)

Comment: @Cai wow, you're completely correct. This enables intra-word emphasis. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cai I answered it.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option called `asteriskIntraWordEmphasis` in [Markdown.Converter.js](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Converter.js#L232) which needs to be set to enable the intra-word emphasis. You pass the options when creating the converter object, so you can enable it by doing something like this:

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter({asteriskIntraWordEmphasis: true});
```

I just tested this using the demo and it seems to work as expected.

You can see this is how it is enabled on the editor here too (in [wmd.en.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=61afee453908)) and that it's stored as a setting on the `StackExchange` object like so:

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter({
    nonAsciiLetters: true,
    asteriskIntraWordEmphasis: StackExchange.settings.markdown.asteriskIntraWordEmphasis,
    autoNewlines: StackExchange.settings.markdown.autoNewlines,
    linkEmails: StackExchange.settings.markdown.linkEmails
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [Cai](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307988/cai) in the comments:

It is actually possible in PageDown, but is disabled by default. There is an option called `asteriskIntraWordEmphasis` that enables `_DoItalicsAndBold_AllowIntrawordWithAsterisk`. The change mentioned at [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works) was probably implemented just by enabling this option.

Answer (score 1):

In `Markdown.Converter.js`, changing this line:

```
var _DoItalicsAndBold = OPTIONS.asteriskIntraWordEmphasis ? _DoItalicsAndBold_AllowIntrawordWithAsterisk : _DoItalicsAndBoldStrict;
```

to

```
var _DoItalicsAndBold = _DoItalicsAndBold_AllowIntrawordWithAsterisk;
```

enables int*r**a-wor***d emphasis!

Comment: Surely it would be better to just set the option.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen how do we do that?

Comment: `new Markdown.Converter({ asteriskIntraWordEmphasis: true })`

Comment: Ps. You may also want to take a look at [how SE instantiates the Markdown converter](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.en.js) (search for `01_01_MarkdownEditor.js`).