# links to external commercial sites, redirect links (for monetization)

Tags: support, amazon

I added an Amazon book link to a comment and it got transformed to:
`http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052`

This performs a redirection to Amazon. If somebody clicks on it, do you get click-money from Amazon partnership for it? If so, good idea to monetize the users input!

Comment: Wow, that's pretty tricky! And smart!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the discussion about it before it got implemented:

- [Auto-inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)
- [Would it be a problem if all Amazon links were converted to affiliate links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10948/would-it-be-a-problem-if-all-amazon-links-were-converted-to-affiliate-links)