# SE is hijacking links?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Please keep in mind that the topic or quality of [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/how-to-wash-lettuce) does not matter.  If you think the answer is weak, that's fine, irrelevant, down vote it.  What matters is the fact that a link that was posted is redirected.

I posted this

`http://www.amazon.com/Oxo-Good-Grips-Salad-Spinner/dp/B00005QB5U`

but it now takes you to this

`http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00005QB5U/?tag=stackoverfl08-20`

I appreciate that the SE sites exist solely because someone is making money, but I feel this is taking it too far.  That's not my own "affiliate" link.  If it were, I would accept the change.  However, it's not.  Pollute the site with advertising all you want (that's to be expected), but don't alter user's post!

Comment: What is the problem here? So they make it an affiliate link of SO/SE. Where's the issue?

Comment: I'm downvoting this for "Pollute the site with advertising all you want (that's to be expected)" No, _hell no_.

Comment: And there's [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

Comment: @Yannis: That's a shame.  I guess you missed the gist of the question.  Asking questions is hard.  Thank you for the writing lesson.

Comment: That's exactly the same page. Why you care for the URL so much??

Comment: No, it doesn't have an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10948/would-it-be-a-problem-if-all-amazon-links-were-converted-to-affiliate-links).  The SE team is conspicuously silent on this issue.

Comment: @raven You're written an excellent rant. But this is not a question, nor the start of a discussion. What is the problem? What harm does the affiliate link cause? What is fundamentally problematic here?

Comment: @raven: [No, they're not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links).

Comment: @raven You don't like something, and you propose an alternative. That's fine, but... your alternative sucks. Hard. Sorry, but that's a downvote in my book. I don't have strong feelings about the affiliate links (actually I couldn't care less), but just the idea that "polluting the site with advertising" is ok is... scary.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. SE is hijacking Amazon links in order to make what must be a tiny amount of money on the side... but then servers must run and it's not like I care that SE might get a few pence from a book I buy (I've never even _seen_ an Amazon link on SE until this point so it's still not likely).

Comment: @Bart: It just feels wrong.  They are altering content, that SE users provide for free, for their own gain.  You want to convert my _non-affiliate_ link to your affiliate link?  Fine, give me a cut.

Comment: True @raven. I mean, the amount of money you've poured into this site must be amazing by now. The membership fees and everything. Not to mention all the in-app purchases and the like. Give me a break. And if that is your problem, the dupe suits just fine.

Comment: @raven I'll personally give you a cut for all amazon links in your answers when you start paying your share for hosting expenses and developer fees.

Comment: You can hardly call an Amazon link _" content, that SE users provide for free"_, I don't think you can call it content. It's either self-promotion (your own book etc.) or just you stating that this is something you like to someone else. Why didn't you link to a picture of a salad spinner rather than an Amazon page of them?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Thank you.  That's what I needed to see.  I'm only four years late to the party, but now I understand.

Comment: @raven this site does not exist to make money, and I regard this question as a bit  petty. Sorry. But SE has to pay overheads to run such a big community based Q&A site, and you, as well and millions of others come here for advice.

Comment: @Skippy I agree with what you say here, but Stack Overflow is a for-profit business. The site *does* exist to make somebody money (among other things).

Comment: @Pekka웃 who makes the profit?

Comment: @raven You realize once you post something on Stack Overflow, it is no longer yours - all posts on SO are licensed under Creative Commons. There's nothing wrong with other people editing it, just as there's nothing wrong with an automated process affiliate-izing the links.

Comment: @Skippy Jeff and the rest of the SE team

Comment: @Skippy, Stack Exchange Inc. is a (Delaware-based, New York-headquartered) private corporation that runs the Stack Exchange Network. As far as I know, they haven't disclosed whether they've yet turned a profit, though they're certainly intending to do so.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta well they've put enough work into it, I did wonder, how can these guys afford to live, they put so much time into the site lol, that makes sense, so its Jeff and Jon's business? like is that how they make a living or do they also do other things?

Comment: @Skippy, venture capital. It's certainly possible to build a business off credit cards and second mortgages, but it's a really bad idea, and only takes you so far. SE Inc. has raised several rounds of venture capital funding. Jeff no longer participates actively in SE, though I'll bet he still has an ownership stake.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta venture capital is this? sorry I don't know what it is... so are you saying they're trying to cover their costs?

Comment: @Skippy, maybe [start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venture_capital). Essentially, venture capital groups provide funding for potential businesses they see as promising, in exchange for an ownership stake. Positives: provide money needed to run the business. Negatives: with ownership, comes the ability to tell you what to do, how to run your business.

Comment: thanks @MichaelPetrotta that makes it clear

Comment: @Skippy See also: [What is Stack Overflow's business model](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model). That answer is a bit out of date now, but the gist of it is still true - not counting venture capital funding, we make most of our money through [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) and ad sales.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I understand.  I apologize for my seemingly "trollish" post, but this was the first time I encountered this link switching policy of yours and I found it jarring.  An unnecessary, knee-jerk reaction on my part.

Comment: @raven It's all good.

Comment: Workaround: Use a URL shortener that redirects to the link. This way, the engine can't change the link, as the redirect URL cannot be changed.

Answer (score 4):

As the linked dupes state, SE does do this.

What's wrong with that? *Something* has to happen to the affiliate cash. Is it all that important that it goes to Amazon? Something has to pay the bills around here, and it's OK to insert your own link when you own the site.

As one of the linked answers says,

> Are you an Amazon stockholder?

The links both go to the same page, and one gets the owners of the best QA sites in the world money to run their servers. Which one would you rather have?

I agree with you *in principle* that links shouldn't be changed automatically. In this case, however, the community agreed that it's OK for SE to automatically insert their affiliate code.